# Mask Hash Function - php

Tags: php

I'd like to hash a file using php's hash_file(), but obfuscate it so it is not easily detected by a text string search in a text editor. Any advice? Possible?

Comment: You don't want the string 'hash_file' to appear in your code, or what?

Comment: Yes thats what I mean. I id like to use the hash_file() function, but obfuscate it so it cant be detected by a text file search.

Comment: I'm researching anti piracy tactics.

Comment: @atwell This is a terrible "anti-piracy" tactic. All you are doing is wasting your time **and** making your code harder to read and maintain.

Comment: How is it terrible when I haven't even disclosed a tactic? I'm not looking to compile my code. I want it open source. So my best lead is to booby trap it for a deterrent. This will help me go about it. I'd like my booby trap to be as hard to *easily* detect as possible. I'd use hash_file to form a trigger.

Comment: ... Maintaining the booby trap would add some responsibility though.

Comment: @atwell What's the point of obfuscating it if you want to make it open source? I mean, if you want people to look at your code, why would you want to make it hard to read?

Answer (score 0):

You could use base64_encode/base64_decode to mask the name of the command being executed.

```
$command = "hash_file";
$encodedcommand = base64_encode($command); //aGFzaF9maWxl
```

Now you know that the base64 encoding of 'hash_file' is aGFzaF9maWxl.

So in your real script, just decode and execute that string:

```
$maskedcommand = base64_decode("aGFzaF9maWxl");
print $maskedcommand("md5",$filename);
```

So the string 'hash_file' isn't in the two lines of code above, but it still executes the 'hash_file' command.